# Advice on how to synchronize bewteen 2 actors- one add/remove from list and other clean list

Tags: c++, multithreading

I need advice in design and c++ implementation (I am a java guy, new to c++).

I have list of processes.
One thread add/remove process to the list and second thread once in 10ms runs and collects all processes (and removes them from the list) that have timed out. Each process has a creation timestamp when it was added to the list. If 3 sec have passed and the process is still in the list (not removed by the first thread) it is removed from the list by the cleaner process.

This has to be with low overhead.

So I have processListContainer with 3 methods:
add, remove , clean

need to sync between the add/removeById and the clean.
This can be done by clever thinking such as creating a new list when cleaning, and handle multiple lists.

The list size is around 100K and thousands added in sec

Comment: Is `add` always to the tail, and `remove` always from the head?

Comment: The add and remove is done by the same thread. i dosnt care to where to add . the remove is dosnt from the tail or head . this thread can get a request to remove element id - x and it need to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can organize your list of processes into a list of sublists. Each sublist is a collection of processes that would expire within the same 5ms interval. This would allow your `cleaner` thread to clear out an entire sublist when it is deciding to remove stale processes, instead of iterating through individual processes.

The list initially contains an empty sublist.

The `clean` operation is a loop with the exit condition being either the head sublist is empty or the head sublist is not expirable. If  the head sublist has expired, it cleans out the list. If the list has more than 1 sublist, it removes the resulting empty sublist. The loop repeats.

So, `add` would check to see if the process belongs to the last sublist. If so, it adds itself to that sublist. If not, it creates a new sublist, and adds  itself to it, and adds the sublist to the list.

The `remove` element removes the provided element from the sublist. If the sublist becomes empty, and there is more than one sublist in the list, it removes the empty sublist.

In this scheme, `add` should not need to lock, since it only manipulates the tail, or an unexpirable sublist. `clean` and `remove` both need locks since they may both manipulate the head of the list.

Comment: I like the concept, but it would require a hand-crafted structure to avoid locking I think.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: This would likely be a custom data structure.

Comment: @user1495181: Thanks for the info, I updated the answer. Basically, as long as the list and sublist are doubly linked lists, the removal is still O(1) (provided you have an O(1) lookup from id to process).

Comment: remove is by id , so need to search in all exist sublists. i didnt understand why it O(1).  i agree with you that this should be the design , because in this way. the clean work on small lists and chance to contention is small. Thank you

Comment: @user1495181: You can use a hash table (`std::unordered_map`) to associated id to sublist element.

Comment: @user315052: the problem is that then you also need the "massive cleanup" thread to remove the cleaned-up ids from the `unordered_map` lest it grows continuously (space leak)... and thus you have contention on this `unordered_map` and the massive clean is no longer O(1).

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I was assuminig each process needed to be individually destructed anyway. So I never expected `cleaner` to operator O(1), but O(n), where n is the number that have expired. This is an improvement over O(N), where N is the total number of processes. I was only referring to the `remove` task being O(1) instead of O(N).

Answer (score 0):

You only need to keep one list, and protect it with a mutex. Also I'd avoid a 'cleaner' process, and have processes remove themselves from the list when they complete.

Comment: The list is huge (100K), so have timer on every element is very expensive.